# Widget not showing JSON result

Tags: android, json, android-widget

I'm creating a widget that is supposed to get weather information from a website that provides a JSON service and show it. Here is the code

Widget:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {



public static void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int appWidgetIds) {
    String resultadoObtido = "";

    SharedPreferences c = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String cidade = c.getString("cidade", "Coimbra");

    try {
        Dados d = new Dados(cidade);
        resultadoObtido = d.execute().get();

    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();                    
    }               
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String string = resultadoObtido;

    String[] parts = string.split("/");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String part3 = parts[2];
    String part4 = parts[3];
    String part5 = parts[4];

    float atual =Float.parseFloat(part1);
    float minima =Float.parseFloat(part2);
    float maxima = Float.parseFloat(part3);

    float atualC = (float) (atual-273.15);
    float minimaC  = (float) (minima-273.15);
    float maximaC = (float) (maxima-273.15);

    String result1 =String.format("%.1f", atualC);
    String result2 =String.format("%.1f", minimaC);
    String result3 =String.format("%.1f", maximaC);

    RemoteViews view =new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);

    view.setTextViewText(R.id.cidade,""+part4);
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp,""+result1+"ºC");
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp_max,""+result2+"ºC");
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp_min,""+result3+"ºC");




}
```

}

class dados that gets the service:
    public class Dados extends AsyncTask {

```
String Resultado = "";
public String s,city;
public Dados(String cidade){
    city=cidade;        
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        s = getJson("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+",pt");
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject detalhe= jobj.getJSONObject("main");
        JSONArray weather = jobj.getJSONArray("weather");
        Resultado = detalhe.getString("temp")+"/"+detalhe.getString("temp_min")+"/"
        +detalhe.getString("temp_max")+"/"+jobj.getString("name")
        +"/"+weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("main");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return Resultado;
}

public String getJson (String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String con;
    while ((con=reader.readLine())!= null){
        build.append(con);
    }
    return build.toString();

}
```

}

Config:

```
public class Config extends Activity{

private int myWidgetId;
Context context;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    setContentView(R.layout.config);

    final EditText cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    context=Config.this;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras!=null) {
        myWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    if(myWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID ){
        finish();
    }
    Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String city = cidade.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("Cidade", city);
            editor.commit();

            AppWidgetManager appWMan= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            MainActivity.onUpdate(context, appWMan,myWidgetId);
            Intent resultvalue = getIntent();
            resultvalue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,myWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,resultvalue);
            finish();


        }
    });

}
```

}

I don't get any errors but the widget only shows the textViews with the default text.
can anyone figure out this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add onPostExecute method in you asynctask to set data to TextView and write your asynctask class inside MainActivity class.

So your MainActivity class will look like follows

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
       Context context;


       public static void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int appWidgetIds) {
         this.context=context;

         SharedPreferences c = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         String cidade = c.getString("cidade", "Coimbra");

         try {
            new Dados(cidade).execute();
         } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();                    
         } catch (ExecutionException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      public class Dados extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
         public String s,city;
         public Dados(String cidade){
            city=cidade;        
         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {          
           String Resultado = "";

           try {
               s = getJson("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+",pt");
               JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
               JSONObject detalhe= jobj.getJSONObject("main");
               JSONArray weather = jobj.getJSONArray("weather");
               Resultado = detalhe.getString("temp")+"/"+detalhe.getString("temp_min")+"/"
            +detalhe.getString("temp_max")+"/"+jobj.getString("name")
            +"/"+weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("main");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return Resultado;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);        

        if(result!=null && !result.trim().isEmpty()){

            String[] parts = result.split("/");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            String part3 = parts[2];
            String part4 = parts[3];
            String part5 = parts[4];

            float atual =Float.parseFloat(part1);
            float minima =Float.parseFloat(part2);
            float maxima = Float.parseFloat(part3);

            float atualC = (float) (atual-273.15);
            float minimaC  = (float) (minima-273.15);
            float maximaC = (float) (maxima-273.15);

            String result1 =String.format("%.1f", atualC);
            String result2 =String.format("%.1f", minimaC);
            String result3 =String.format("%.1f", maximaC);

            RemoteViews view =new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);

            view.setTextViewText(R.id.cidade,""+part4);
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp,""+result1+"ºC");
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp_max,""+result2+"ºC");
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.temp_min,""+result3+"ºC");
        }
    }

    public String getJson (String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String con;
        while ((con=reader.readLine())!= null){
            build.append(con);
        }
        return build.toString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: That's the thing I told you. write your async task inside MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved the problem by moving this part of the code

```
try {
    Dados d = new Dados(cidade);
    resultadoObtido = d.execute().get();

}catch (InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();                    
}               
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String string = resultadoObtido;

String[] parts = string.split("/");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3 = parts[2];
String part4 = parts[3];
String part5 = parts[4];

float atual =Float.parseFloat(part1);
float minima =Float.parseFloat(part2);
float maxima = Float.parseFloat(part3);

float atualC = (float) (atual-273.15);
float minimaC  = (float) (minima-273.15);
float maximaC = (float) (maxima-273.15);

String result1 =String.format("%.1f", atualC);
String result2 =String.format("%.1f", minimaC);
String result3 =String.format("%.1f", maximaC);
```

to a class that extends service and then calling the service on the widget.